# MySql insert query not working in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
            $con = mysql_connect("localhost:3306","root","");
            try
            {
                if (!$con)
                 {
                     die('Could not connect to MySql Server : ' . mysql_error());
                }

                $db_found = mysql_select_db("registerdb");  

                if ($db_found) 
                {
                    print "Database Found";
                }
                else 
                {
                    print "Database NOT Found";
                }
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO register VALUES ('$_POST[Field2]','$_POST[Field4]','$_POST[Field7]','$_POST[Field8]','$_POST[Field9]','$_POST[Field13]','$_POST[Field14]','$_POST[Field15]')");

                mysql_close($con);
            }
            catch(Exception $e)
            {
                echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
            }
?>
```

I am not getting any error at run time, select query working fine for same database.
Here is the table defination for register

```
 Name          Type           Null      Key
 id       bigint(10)      NO        PRI     auto_increment
sname     varchar(20)     NO             
dob       date  YES       NULL   
email     varchar(30)     NO             
gender    varchar(7)      NO             
mobile    int(10)     YES            
country       varchar(15)     NO             
state     varchar(15)     YES            
city      varchar(15)     YES
```

I am not getting any sysntax error in php.

Sorry for my mistakes, I edited it.

Comment: Start using PDO or mysqli, and stop using mysql since it's deprecated. Also mysql doesn't throw exceptions, so the try catch is kind of useless :)

Comment: You're missing a `'` on the last value `'$_POST[Field15]`

Comment: Voting to close as too localised due to typo. A typo that could have more easily been avoided with parametrized queries, for example. =)

Comment: also use ('".$_POST['Field4']."', '".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the syntax was wrong,

```
Insert into register ('field1','field2',...,'field n') values ('value1','value2',..,'value n');
```

Comment: And the same don't use the $_POST[value] in query. Better assign the value to some variable like, $field1 = $_POST[field1]. after that use this variable in query.

Comment: Nope, there are good reasons to list the field names, but if you insert into concecutive fields starting with the first one, they are not mandatory.

Comment: Actually if you mention like $_POST['value'] in query it will give an error.

Comment: @Sibi_it For auto increment column id suggestion is correct. I am .Net developer thought that mysql will automatically increments value like sql server.

Comment: Voting up because I hate when people clearly accepts the answer but don't vote up for it.

Comment: @bowlerae some one has vote it down, initially it was -1, I woted it by -1 to 0, you vote to 1. got it.

Answer (score 2):

```
,'$_POST[Field15])'");
                  ^_______________ Missed quote.
```

Use parameters instead POST data concatenation to avoid potential SQL Injection.

Answer (score 1):

You messed up your 4th variable:

```
POST[Field4] [Should Be] $_POST[Field4]
```

You also missed a closing quote after Field15

To avoid any erros, it is also a good idea to include your schema in the query:

```
INSERT INTO example_table (field1, field2, field3) VALUES (value1, value2, value3);
```

**EDIT**

How about we try for an all out escaped Query...

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO register VALUES ("'.$_POST['Field2'].'","'.$_POST['Field4'].'","'.$_POST['Field7'].'","'.$_POST['Field8'].'","'.$_POST['Field9'].'","'.$_POST['Field13'].'","'.$_POST['Field14'].'","'.$_POST['Field15'].'")');
```

Comment: Huh, I honestly didn't know that you didn't need the schema.... The more you know ^.^

Comment: @Matt Clark just edited my question, i tried it, still not working.

Comment: @Mayur see my edit, and also, could you post your HTTP query with all POST variables?

Comment: @Matt Clark it was auto increment issue, i was passing minimum parameters , I did not pass DEFAULT keyword for auto increment.

Comment: So... what you are saying is that my very first post, the one that I edited because everybody downvoted, was actually the correct answer, and even though I still have the correct answer in my post, somebody else got marked as correct? Awesome, glad to help!

Comment: @Matt Clark he posted his answer before you, but someone downvoted it.  So he gets his point back.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see any problems here, but I guess the 'POST[Field4]' is a typo - but as others have said, you should really not use the mysql_ functions.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query does not throw exceptions, you have to check it's return value and call mysql_error for further information.

As stated in the comments, mysql ist deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

It should be like:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO table(column 1, column 2, column 3) VALUES('".$value1."','".$value2."', '".$value3."')";
```

Try this.